# Android Open GL interfaces

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opengl-es

I'm working in a AR (augmented reality) Android app with android studio and I wonder if there is any framework to create Open GL user interfaces, like dialogs, buttons, image and video containers and so on... Any Ideas?

Comment: **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Oh really? forums are opinionated by nature, and yes, this is a forum. Tanks anyway, you should consider trying to give an answer instead of a critic.

Comment: The problem with posts like yours is that they tend to attract spam. A quote from [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251135/4733879): "Most recommendation questions are poorly specified magnets for spam and bikeshedding, so we don't accept questions of this type on any Stack Exchange site."

The second issue is that this post falls out of the allowed topics defined on the [on-topic](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page in the SO help center.

Comment: Another critic, no answer... OMG! do you know the framework or not?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Viro?

https://viromedia.com/viroar/

We offer both a React-Native (ViroReact) and a native Java API (ViroCore).

You won't be coding in OpenGL yourself (we write the renderer), but you get an easy-to-use scene-graph API. ViroCore is analogous to SceneKit, but for Android.

It's free to use and distribute!

Check out our:

Docs: https://virocore.viromedia.com/docs/getting-started
Samples: https://github.com/viromedia/virocore

Let us know if you have any questions!

Disclaimer: I do work at Viro, if that wasn't obvious :)

Comment: Thanks for recommending Viro I'll take a look... by the way, I don't see any pricing, nor licensing information on the website, what if I use Viro in a comercial project?

Comment: Another thing is that Viro relies on ARCore... not an option for the project due compatibility restrictions.

Comment: Hi @PedroEmilioBorregoRached Sorry, the website is a bit convoluted, but you can check out our license here at ViroCore: https://virocore.viromedia.com/docs/license. TL;DR, the platform is free to use and you can ship commercial apps, but attribution is required: https://virocore.viromedia.com/docs/attribution. If you don't want to use ARCore, we have ViroViewScene which is a generic scene graph API which shouldn't load ARCore: https://developer.viromedia.com/virocore/reference/com/viro/core/ViroViewScene.html

Comment: Thank you very much @ACVM, I will for sure give it a try, if it mets the software and performance requirements will be included. Seems well documented also...